# Python scattered chart legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot

I'm plotting a scattered chart which look like this :

```
from pylab import *

n = 1024
X = np.random.normal(0,1,n)
Y = np.random.normal(0,1,n)
T = np.arctan2(Y,X)

axes([0.025,0.025,0.95,0.95])
scatter(X,Y, s=75, c=T, alpha=.5)

xlim(-1.5,1.5), xticks([])
ylim(-1.5,1.5), yticks([])
# savefig('../figures/scatter_ex.png',dpi=48)
show()
```

[image]

I would like to add a legend to explain the color scale :

Like yellow is 0 red is 10 etc...

I cannot find a way to do it , it works for imshow like this one :

```
from pylab import *

def f(x,y): return (1-x/2+x**5+y**3)*np.exp(-x**2-y**2)

n = 10
x = np.linspace(-3,3,3.5*n)
y = np.linspace(-3,3,3.0*n)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = f(X,Y)

axes([0.025,0.025,0.95,0.95])
imshow(Z,interpolation='nearest', cmap='bone', origin='lower')
colorbar(shrink=.92)

xticks([]), yticks([])
# savefig('../figures/imshow_ex.png', dpi=48)
show()
```

[image]

BUt I cannot find a way to add it on scattered charts.

DOes anyone already had to deal with this issue ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last few lines to:

```
>>> s = scatter(X,Y, s=75, c=T, alpha=.5)
>>> colorbar(s)
>>> show()
```

[image]

Comment: yes... but the color bar is not so good. Now, how do you obtain an step colorbar or continuous colorbar?